# NFT on polygon community mint or directly list to secondary market

Tags: blockchain, nft, polygon

Guys I am about to release an NFT art collection project with one influencer and his community.
I am planning to mint all the 10000 items and list them on opensea (polygon). It will be easier for me in this "speedrun" as we call it. Do you see a critical down side of this strategy (instead of asking the community to mint the nfts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're not using your own smart contract, so you'd have to manually mint 10k NFTs on the OpenSea UI. I don't think this can be automated, as solving a captcha for each one is required. To me the time this would take is a critical downside.

Instead, I'd use my own smart contract, and let users pay for minting, as described here:
https://docs.opensea.io/docs/minting-from-your-new-contract-and-improvements

---

Edit: Since you're using your own smart contract, and pre-minting 10k NFTs is no problem for you (as opposed to OpenSea's "mint-on-demand" solution mentioned above), then there's the challenge of listing each item of your collection. Fortunately there's an [API endpoint to create listings](https://docs.opensea.io/v2.0/reference/create-an-order).

The only remaining downside of this approach I potentially see is regarding how it's displayed on OpenSea. Under "Item Activity" every item of your collection will have the same "Minted"-entry. (The first buyer won't be the one who minted the NFT.)

So I think it comes down to how you want it to look and behave on OpenSea.

Comment: I am using my own smart contract and I will mint them, that is not an issue for me

Comment: I edited my response, in short: I don't see any problematic downside of your strategy. Even the OpenSea docs themselves say: "The simplest way to sell your items on OpenSea is to simply mint the items into an account that you own and put them on sale..."

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, it's able to mint NFT on the Opensea's polygon network for free. and after the first sale the platform charge the cost of creation. so there is concern about Gas cost.

if you want to mint all 10000 NFTs at once, it'd be better to use Opensea SDK instead of doing that manually through the UI of the platform.
I think the down side is that technically because the owner of these items are Opensea because it pays the gas. regarding the numbers of items, you should accept the rules of Opensea.
Please correct me if there is a mistake ;)

**plz vote me up if it is useful**

Answer (score 1):

You can MINT 10k NFTs in one go! And you can do it without writing any code. The process is fully automated and you will also have a dedicated contract for your collection.

Yes, it is possible through polygon's batch minting solution.
Check out their minting solution site https://mintnft.today/.
You can do a batch mint, provided you have the metadata for all NFTs in a csv/json format.
You will also get a personalized collection created on opensea.
Here's the [demo](https://app.usebubbles.com/6XSPfg1un3x96cAX7hvWoK/mint-nft-batch-mint-demo) on how to use it.